# Exact definition of Characteristic polynomial of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, definition

For a matrix $A$, Is there any difference to state the characteristic polynomial in terms of $\det(A-\lambda I)$ or $\det(\lambda I - A)$?

Because I need to replace the $\lambda$ with some other values which are not its roots, so I think based on the definition, the results will be different. I would like to know which one is the polynomial characteristic of $A$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've seem both of them used as definition, although I think that I've seen far more often the first option. Anyway, they are either equal is one of them is minus the other one. Therefore, they have the same roots (which are the eigenvalues of $A$).

Comment: Yes the roots are the same, It is important to me to know which one to use. This choice will completely alter my results

Comment: As you can see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_polynomial#Formal_definition), there is no universal agreement on that. How can your results depend on that?

Comment: If $P(x)$ is a monic polynomial of order $n$ and $x_1, x_n$ are the min and max values of its roots, then for any $y > x_n$, $P(y) > 0$ and for any $z < x_1 , (-1)^{n}P(z) > 0$. I need to use the results of this. But if the $P$ is a char.poly of a matrix, then I need to know which definition I should  use.

Comment: @Drupalist SInce this is what you're interested in, you should use the $\det(\lambda\operatorname{Id}-A)$ definition.